# Размер интерактивной карты svg

Tags: svg

Есть интерактивная карта сделанная с помощью `svg`, я задаю её размеры через картинку `<img src="media/back.png" alt="">`. Если я картинку убираю, то моя карта уменьшается до очень маленьких размеров. 
 Картинка тех же размеров что и в `viewBox`.

Как исправить? (Я пытаюсь избавиться от картинки)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Интерактивная карта</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="keywords" content=" ">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico"> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="map">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 662">
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/1.jpg'> Мощно.">
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.85671,381.31123 17.70329,8.50142 8.37328,-16.95909 -17.95597,-8.75942 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 364.5027,269.75233 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,354.8261 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 457.8629,407.85911 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 438.52794,447.63388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 361.18814,458.68241 8.5976,7.21778 7.0639,-8.08786 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,437.13775 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 393.22891,420.01251 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 368.92212,550.38533 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 379.97066,522.76397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 399.30561,492.93291 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 635.92316,259.30512 13.52116,11.21884 11.10914,-12.57123 -13.68345,-11.4954 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 570.29179,252.37179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 540.60429,239.87179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.46366,286.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 426.15116,306.66867 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 453.88554,326.59054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 513.65116,357.44993 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 479.66679,339.48117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 552.32303,326.98117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 587.47928,303.54367 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 619.51054,278.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 737.35191,384.86418 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 762.42044,409.09176 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 835.36871,399.06991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 801.77496,415.47616 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 870.52496,388.91366 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1019.5465,416.09124 8.3179,6.76687 7.3516,-8.50865 -8.4144,-6.93973 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 975.99371,413.13241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 936.93121,422.50741 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 911.93121,442.81991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.89996,449.85116 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 849.43121,456.88241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 825.99371,469.38241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 793.92242,478.74251 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 752.32304,474.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 721.07304,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 690.60429,430.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 504.66679,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 572.63554,393.77804 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 600.76054,371.12179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 625.76054,349.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 655.44804,324.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 685.13554,303.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 802.32304,295.34054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 742.16679,184.40304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 717.94804,161.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 818.59784,217.82417 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 851.74347,237.71155 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.91726,255.38921 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 906.98619,276.38145 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 937.92211,291.84941 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 966.64832,308.42223 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 861.13473,315.05136 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 890.9658,333.83388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 924.6639,354.82611 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1037.359,437.13776 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1066.6377,448.73873 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1093.7065,465.86397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1122.9852,482.43679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1224.7151,393.76316 15.2144,9.97674 9.3518,-13.10396 -15.4178,-10.23515 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat1.jpg'> ул.Азамат,1">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1284.9949,443.66556 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat5.jpg'> ул.Азамат,5">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1189.6159,408.49403 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 999.00976,327.22136 8.59764,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1025.4651,345.98622 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1052.5358,361.36727 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1162.9716,437.04199 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1083.2978,383.51597 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1118.0589,405.04942 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1185.4279,365.67396 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1153.1277,348.75482 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1119.5971,324.14514 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1086.6817,304.45742 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1059.3236,291.00257 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1038.4417,274.471 8.5975,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1006.2486,250.97876 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 971.01023,232.70701 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 948.82312,217.48056 8.59753,7.21777 7.06395,-8.08785 -8.70082,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 919.24029,198.77377 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 892.26772,183.11227 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 863.11994,158.74995 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 814.83033,130.90729 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 784.37742,107.8501 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395715 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 754.7946,93.058683 8.59753,7.217777 7.06396,-8.08786 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 728.69211,77.397188 8.59753,7.217768 7.06396,-8.087851 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 696.93407,54.339988 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395711 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 674.31438,42.065815 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.087853 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 484.63627,0.3018283 -14.35637,22.1871177 100.92963,61.775898 5.65554,-8.70083 -4.35041,-2.61025 6.09058,-9.570913 -45.24432,-30.452908 2.17521,-3.915374 -9.13588,-6.960664 1.74017,-4.350415 -26.10249,-17.4016617 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 436.34666,39.020525 -10.00596,17.401661 31.32299,19.141828 10.00596,-16.96662 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 427.21079,92.530633 -28.2777,43.939197 18.27174,12.18116 28.2777,-43.93919 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 360.21439,86.875093 -9.13587,15.226457 39.58878,24.79736 9.13587,-14.35637 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 394.86582,9.472205 -29.58282,50.029766 26.10249,16.53158 30.88795,-50.02978 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 232.74722,39.455566 -6.09058,19.576869 21.75208,6.960665 6.09058,-18.706786 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 190.11315,32.929943 -4.35042,23.492243 23.05721,4.785457 4.35041,-23.057201 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 161.83545,23.794071 17.40166,5.220498 -6.09058,23.927285 -17.8367,-6.090582 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 354.54093,577.40427 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 328.08553,568.17564 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 298.86155,571.25185 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 265.02327,578.32713 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 226.57067,584.47955 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 184.119,576.4814 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 150.89595,581.09572 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 119.04926,586.01766 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 146.60058,4.6042554 h -6.57465 V 16.304109 l -10.95773,40.54135 -2.79014,9.655026 -2.5669,9.706155 -1.5625,9.278 3.04891,3.822735 4.30192,-2.03664 1.52699,-6.59213 1.51677,-7.664099 1.72987,-8.006358 77.25208,19.862541 10.40985,1.632537 101.10559,12.215169 1.88355,-6.245694 -100.2497,-13.043804 -87.66194,-21.49508 10.95775,-39.180902 z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 381.17475,4.0592369 C 367.21517,29.839172 351.33443,55.619106 339.4665,81.399041 c -10.65482,8.821069 -12.27478,16.943774 -19.05874,25.411649 -0.0687,3.27136 1.93385,3.87968 4.41942,3.86699 L 347.20047,80.5704 387.25145,6.2689456 c -0.52067,-2.8219703 -1.89786,-4.5061728 -6.0767,-2.2097087 z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 462.38154,376.39515 8.28641,4.97185 -60.76699,87.83592 -43.64174,61.87184 -21.54466,26.5165 -23.75437,7.73398 -212.68446,10.49612 -1.10486,-7.73398 212.68446,-11.60097 20.43981,-7.73398 33.14563,-45.29903 z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1000,374.5 -18.75,13.28125 -175,73.4375 -8.59375,-2.34375 -82.03125,-50 -5.46875,5.46875 78.90625,50.78125 13.06176,1.59199 8.2864,-0.55242 17.81578,-6.35292 170.99231,-72.42103 7.81255,-7.03125 z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 1355.6563,433.29515 680.59028,6.8213731 676.17086,11.24079 1353.4466,443.23884 Z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1301.5625,412.19531 7.8125,4.6875 -55.4687,38.47656 c 0,0 -38.4766,26.36719 -39.4532,26.36719 -0.9765,0 -8.789,2.92969 -8.789,2.92969 l -11.3166,1.3957 -17.9538,-0.55243 -11.8772,-5.24806 -132.5825,-87.83592 -103.58014,-64.35777 -116.83834,-73.74902 -33.42185,-21.54466 -13.81068,-3.59078 -6.62912,-1.10485 -11.87719,2.76213 -8.56262,5.52427 -15.46796,14.91554 -74.57767,70.15825 -48.33737,39.49854 -38.94612,34.25049 -14.63932,10.77233 -11.60097,3.59077 -9.94369,0.27622 -89.21699,-51.09952 -12.01071,-6.37978 -12.5723,-6.87847 -41.70825,-27.34515 -5.71587,-7.95534 7.09251,-0.82051 57.89956,33.23088 22.41019,14.25781 20.02913,10.83796 30.9609,19.84434 9.71169,5.87307 14.22499,6.35291 10.91044,0.13811 9.52937,-4.83374 55.93325,-47.23253 -29.27864,-36.18397 -24.72111,-31.35025 5.10995,-3.72888 49.16602,60.76699 5.24805,5.80048 39.08423,-32.17888 78.82201,-75.49503 -78.125,-51.95313 -25.78125,-14.84375 3.51562,-5.46875 25.39063,14.84375 25.78125,-37.89062 5.07812,2.73437 -24.60937,37.5 74.21875,49.21875 11.71875,-5.85937 10.9375,-4.29688 19.92187,2.73438 21.09375,10.9375 126.5625,80.07812 156.6406,99.21875 91.7969,59.375 19.9219,5.85938 15.625,-0.78125 z" fill="#789A5F">>
    </a>
   </svg>
    
   <div class="description">
    
   </div>

   <img src="media/back.png" alt="">
  </div>


 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: можно пояснить подробней, как вы задаете размер svg карты, через растровую картинку png? png картинка у вас встроена внутрь svg?

Comment: внутри body у класса map внутри вставляется картинка. таким образом я могу нормально отображать карту. иначе не получается. как я понимаю по коду картинка не внутри svg.

Comment: код svg карты, можете  сюда, в сниппет,добавить? А то, как я понял, вы только код svg ромбиков дали

Comment: извините, я не знаю как код в сниппет добавлять.у меня там 371 строка кода. тут не умещается. Скажите пожалуйста как код добавить, я добавлю.

Comment: я смог добавить полносью код в пост. взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: теперь к этой картинке нужно добавить ваши маркеры (ромбики)?

Comment: там не только ромбики, но и дороги. я хочу убрать картинку но не могу этого сделать, так как вся карта сжимается до маленьких размеров.

Comment: уберите ошибки из кода -1. fill="#1669ad">> должно быть fill="#1669ad" />   2.команда. <img>  это команда Html , её не должно быть внутри svg

Comment: ошибки устранил. если я убираю <img>, то у меня нет карты как таковой. вот взгляните пожалуйста. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840441 Если  я переношу картинку оттуда или вообще ее убираю, карты нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в моем случае всё решается просто. Из кода удаляем три строки:
Первая, которая создает бесполезный класс

```
<div class="map">
```

Вторая, которая закрывает этот бесполезный класс, и третью строку, которая ставит на фон изображение

```
</div>
<img src="media/back.png" alt="">
```

После этого всё работает как надо.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то растровая картинка это сама карта. А svg,- это интерактивные маркеры на ней, по клику на которых происходит переход по ссылке.

В этом случае, чтобы растровая картинка и маркеры на ней не теряли свою изначальную позицию при смене размера окна браузера, то необходимо включить растровую картинку непосредственно в файл svg

`<image xlink:href="MoscowMap.png"  width="100%" height="100%" />`

Маркеры svg поместить в секцию `<defs>` и размещать их на карте с помощью команды `<use>`

```html
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1366 662" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
         <defs> 
   <rect id="rec" transform="rotate(45 6 6)" width="12" height="12" fill="#BF2523" />
        </defs>   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUgSr.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%" />             
    
        <a href="#">
            <use xlink:href="#rec" x="380" y="380" />
        </a> 
  
   <a href="#">
            <use xlink:href="#rec" x="580" y="420" />
        </a> 
  
   <a href="#">
            <use xlink:href="#rec" x="700" y="420" />
        </a>
      </svg>
```

Маркеры остаются на месте при любом изменении масштаба

Comment: извините за мое не понимание. касательно картинки изначально это был скриншот карты. но теперь я прорисовал дома и улицы. и я заменил картинку на белый фон. я не хочу картинку оставлять, я  пытаюсь ее убрать. Под маркерами svg вы подразумеваете это?
 <path class="part" d="m 784.37742,107.8501 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395715 z" fill="#1669ad">> При клике я ничего не делаю. Просто появляется окошко при наведении с информацией.

Comment: @Ruslan да, именно это я назвал маркерами - ромбики красно-коричневые А код добавить в сниппет CTRL+M в редакторе вашего вопроса,

Comment: Код я добавил. Взгляните пожалуйста. Если сделать файл html и добавить туда код, можно увидеть очертания всех объектов карты. Вы не знаете как сделать масштабирование? Чтобы можно было бы приближать вплоть до домов? Я пытался использовать svg pan zoom скачанный с github , но все мои попытки провалились.