# Как и с помощью чего масштабировать svg?

Tags: svg

Есть карта сделанная при помощи svg. Как сделать масштабирование? Чтобы можно было приближать и удалять карту.

```js
$('.part').hover(
  function() {
    $('.description').html($(this).attr('description-data'));
    $('.description').fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $('.description').fadeOut(1);
  }
)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(../img/grid.jpg) repeat;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.part {
  opacity: .3;
}

.part:hover {
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 10px #ccc;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: calc(50% - 200px);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.description img {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Интерактивная карта</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content=" ">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="map">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 662">
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/1.jpg'> Мощно.">
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.85671,381.31123 17.70329,8.50142 8.37328,-16.95909 -17.95597,-8.75942 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 364.5027,269.75233 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,354.8261 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 457.8629,407.85911 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 438.52794,447.63388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 361.18814,458.68241 8.5976,7.21778 7.0639,-8.08786 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,437.13775 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 393.22891,420.01251 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 368.92212,550.38533 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 379.97066,522.76397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 399.30561,492.93291 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 635.92316,259.30512 13.52116,11.21884 11.10914,-12.57123 -13.68345,-11.4954 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 570.29179,252.37179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 540.60429,239.87179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.46366,286.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 426.15116,306.66867 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 453.88554,326.59054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 513.65116,357.44993 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 479.66679,339.48117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 552.32303,326.98117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 587.47928,303.54367 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 619.51054,278.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 737.35191,384.86418 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 762.42044,409.09176 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 835.36871,399.06991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 801.77496,415.47616 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 870.52496,388.91366 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1019.5465,416.09124 8.3179,6.76687 7.3516,-8.50865 -8.4144,-6.93973 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 975.99371,413.13241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 936.93121,422.50741 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 911.93121,442.81991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.89996,449.85116 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 849.43121,456.88241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 825.99371,469.38241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 793.92242,478.74251 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 752.32304,474.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 721.07304,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 690.60429,430.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 504.66679,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 572.63554,393.77804 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 600.76054,371.12179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 625.76054,349.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 655.44804,324.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 685.13554,303.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 802.32304,295.34054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 742.16679,184.40304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 717.94804,161.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 818.59784,217.82417 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 851.74347,237.71155 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.91726,255.38921 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 906.98619,276.38145 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 937.92211,291.84941 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 966.64832,308.42223 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 861.13473,315.05136 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 890.9658,333.83388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 924.6639,354.82611 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1037.359,437.13776 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1066.6377,448.73873 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1093.7065,465.86397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1122.9852,482.43679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1224.7151,393.76316 15.2144,9.97674 9.3518,-13.10396 -15.4178,-10.23515 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat1.jpg'> ул.Азамат,1">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1284.9949,443.66556 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat5.jpg'> ул.Азамат,5">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1189.6159,408.49403 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 999.00976,327.22136 8.59764,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1025.4651,345.98622 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1052.5358,361.36727 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1162.9716,437.04199 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1083.2978,383.51597 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1118.0589,405.04942 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1185.4279,365.67396 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1153.1277,348.75482 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1119.5971,324.14514 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1086.6817,304.45742 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1059.3236,291.00257 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1038.4417,274.471 8.5975,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1006.2486,250.97876 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 971.01023,232.70701 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 948.82312,217.48056 8.59753,7.21777 7.06395,-8.08785 -8.70082,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 919.24029,198.77377 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 892.26772,183.11227 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 863.11994,158.74995 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 814.83033,130.90729 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 784.37742,107.8501 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395715 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 754.7946,93.058683 8.59753,7.217777 7.06396,-8.08786 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 728.69211,77.397188 8.59753,7.217768 7.06396,-8.087851 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 696.93407,54.339988 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395711 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 674.31438,42.065815 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.087853 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 484.63627,0.3018283 -14.35637,22.1871177 100.92963,61.775898 5.65554,-8.70083 -4.35041,-2.61025 6.09058,-9.570913 -45.24432,-30.452908 2.17521,-3.915374 -9.13588,-6.960664 1.74017,-4.350415 -26.10249,-17.4016617 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 436.34666,39.020525 -10.00596,17.401661 31.32299,19.141828 10.00596,-16.96662 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 427.21079,92.530633 -28.2777,43.939197 18.27174,12.18116 28.2777,-43.93919 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 360.21439,86.875093 -9.13587,15.226457 39.58878,24.79736 9.13587,-14.35637 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 394.86582,9.472205 -29.58282,50.029766 26.10249,16.53158 30.88795,-50.02978 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 232.74722,39.455566 -6.09058,19.576869 21.75208,6.960665 6.09058,-18.706786 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 190.11315,32.929943 -4.35042,23.492243 23.05721,4.785457 4.35041,-23.057201 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 161.83545,23.794071 17.40166,5.220498 -6.09058,23.927285 -17.8367,-6.090582 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 354.54093,577.40427 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 328.08553,568.17564 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 298.86155,571.25185 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 265.02327,578.32713 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 226.57067,584.47955 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 184.119,576.4814 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 150.89595,581.09572 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 119.04926,586.01766 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 146.60058,4.6042554 h -6.57465 V 16.304109 l -10.95773,40.54135 -2.79014,9.655026 -2.5669,9.706155 -1.5625,9.278 3.04891,3.822735 4.30192,-2.03664 1.52699,-6.59213 1.51677,-7.664099 1.72987,-8.006358 77.25208,19.862541 10.40985,1.632537 101.10559,12.215169 1.88355,-6.245694 -100.2497,-13.043804 -87.66194,-21.49508 10.95775,-39.180902 z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 381.17475,4.0592369 C 367.21517,29.839172 351.33443,55.619106 339.4665,81.399041 c -10.65482,8.821069 -12.27478,16.943774 -19.05874,25.411649 -0.0687,3.27136 1.93385,3.87968 4.41942,3.86699 L 347.20047,80.5704 387.25145,6.2689456 c -0.52067,-2.8219703 -1.89786,-4.5061728 -6.0767,-2.2097087 z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 462.38154,376.39515 8.28641,4.97185 -60.76699,87.83592 -43.64174,61.87184 -21.54466,26.5165 -23.75437,7.73398 -212.68446,10.49612 -1.10486,-7.73398 212.68446,-11.60097 20.43981,-7.73398 33.14563,-45.29903 z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1000,374.5 -18.75,13.28125 -175,73.4375 -8.59375,-2.34375 -82.03125,-50 -5.46875,5.46875 78.90625,50.78125 13.06176,1.59199 8.2864,-0.55242 17.81578,-6.35292 170.99231,-72.42103 7.81255,-7.03125 z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 1355.6563,433.29515 680.59028,6.8213731 676.17086,11.24079 1353.4466,443.23884 Z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1301.5625,412.19531 7.8125,4.6875 -55.4687,38.47656 c 0,0 -38.4766,26.36719 -39.4532,26.36719 -0.9765,0 -8.789,2.92969 -8.789,2.92969 l -11.3166,1.3957 -17.9538,-0.55243 -11.8772,-5.24806 -132.5825,-87.83592 -103.58014,-64.35777 -116.83834,-73.74902 -33.42185,-21.54466 -13.81068,-3.59078 -6.62912,-1.10485 -11.87719,2.76213 -8.56262,5.52427 -15.46796,14.91554 -74.57767,70.15825 -48.33737,39.49854 -38.94612,34.25049 -14.63932,10.77233 -11.60097,3.59077 -9.94369,0.27622 -89.21699,-51.09952 -12.01071,-6.37978 -12.5723,-6.87847 -41.70825,-27.34515 -5.71587,-7.95534 7.09251,-0.82051 57.89956,33.23088 22.41019,14.25781 20.02913,10.83796 30.9609,19.84434 9.71169,5.87307 14.22499,6.35291 10.91044,0.13811 9.52937,-4.83374 55.93325,-47.23253 -29.27864,-36.18397 -24.72111,-31.35025 5.10995,-3.72888 49.16602,60.76699 5.24805,5.80048 39.08423,-32.17888 78.82201,-75.49503 -78.125,-51.95313 -25.78125,-14.84375 3.51562,-5.46875 25.39063,14.84375 25.78125,-37.89062 5.07812,2.73437 -24.60937,37.5 74.21875,49.21875 11.71875,-5.85937 10.9375,-4.29688 19.92187,2.73438 21.09375,10.9375 126.5625,80.07812 156.6406,99.21875 91.7969,59.375 19.9219,5.85938 15.625,-0.78125 z" fill="#789A5F">
    </a>
   </svg>

    <div class="description">

    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/6/11/cd5c7ea4f7730c36437201943392a4ac-full.png" alt="">

  </div>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для проверки работы смотрите здесь : [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/xwq5g20r/8/)

`Scale` будет действовать только когда курсор находится в области этого объекта:

```js
function addOnWheel(elem, handler) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    if ('onwheel' in document) {
      elem.addEventListener("wheel", handler);
    } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
      elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", handler);
    } else {
      elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", handler);
    }
  } else {
    text.attachEvent("onmousewheel", handler);
  }
}

var scale = 1;

addOnWheel(text, function(e) {
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
  if (delta > 0) scale += 0.05;
  else scale = Math.max(scale-0.05, 0.1);

  text.style.transform = text.style.WebkitTransform = text.style.MsTransform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1366 662" id="text">
<a href="#">
<path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/1.jpg'> Мощно.">
</a>    
<a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 396.85671,381.31123 17.70329,8.50142 8.37328,-16.95909 -17.95597,-8.75942 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 364.5027,269.75233 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,354.8261 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 457.8629,407.85911 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 438.52794,447.63388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>    
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 361.18814,458.68241 8.5976,7.21778 7.0639,-8.08786 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,437.13775 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 393.22891,420.01251 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 368.92212,550.38533 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 379.97066,522.76397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 399.30561,492.93291 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 635.92316,259.30512 13.52116,11.21884 11.10914,-12.57123 -13.68345,-11.4954 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 570.29179,252.37179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 540.60429,239.87179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 396.46366,286.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 426.15116,306.66867 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 453.88554,326.59054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 513.65116,357.44993 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 479.66679,339.48117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 552.32303,326.98117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 587.47928,303.54367 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 619.51054,278.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 737.35191,384.86418 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 762.42044,409.09176 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 835.36871,399.06991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 801.77496,415.47616 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 870.52496,388.91366 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1019.5465,416.09124 8.3179,6.76687 7.3516,-8.50865 -8.4144,-6.93973 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 975.99371,413.13241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 936.93121,422.50741 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 911.93121,442.81991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 879.89996,449.85116 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 849.43121,456.88241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 825.99371,469.38241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 793.92242,478.74251 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 752.32304,474.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 721.07304,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 690.60429,430.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 504.66679,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 572.63554,393.77804 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 600.76054,371.12179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 625.76054,349.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 655.44804,324.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 685.13554,303.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 802.32304,295.34054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 742.16679,184.40304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 717.94804,161.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 818.59784,217.82417 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 851.74347,237.71155 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 879.91726,255.38921 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 906.98619,276.38145 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 937.92211,291.84941 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 966.64832,308.42223 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 861.13473,315.05136 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 890.9658,333.83388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 924.6639,354.82611 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1037.359,437.13776 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1066.6377,448.73873 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1093.7065,465.86397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1122.9852,482.43679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1224.7151,393.76316 15.2144,9.97674 9.3518,-13.10396 -15.4178,-10.23515 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat1.jpg'> ул.Азамат,1">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1284.9949,443.66556 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat5.jpg'> ул.Азамат,5">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1189.6159,408.49403 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 999.00976,327.22136 8.59764,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1025.4651,345.98622 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1052.5358,361.36727 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1162.9716,437.04199 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1083.2978,383.51597 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1118.0589,405.04942 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1185.4279,365.67396 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1153.1277,348.75482 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1119.5971,324.14514 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1086.6817,304.45742 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1059.3236,291.00257 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1038.4417,274.471 8.5975,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1006.2486,250.97876 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 971.01023,232.70701 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 948.82312,217.48056 8.59753,7.21777 7.06395,-8.08785 -8.70082,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 919.24029,198.77377 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 892.26772,183.11227 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 863.11994,158.74995 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 814.83033,130.90729 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 784.37742,107.8501 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395715 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 754.7946,93.058683 8.59753,7.217777 7.06396,-8.08786 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 728.69211,77.397188 8.59753,7.217768 7.06396,-8.087851 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 696.93407,54.339988 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395711 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 674.31438,42.065815 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.087853 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 484.63627,0.3018283 -14.35637,22.1871177 100.92963,61.775898 5.65554,-8.70083 -4.35041,-2.61025 6.09058,-9.570913 -45.24432,-30.452908 2.17521,-3.915374 -9.13588,-6.960664 1.74017,-4.350415 -26.10249,-17.4016617 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 436.34666,39.020525 -10.00596,17.401661 31.32299,19.141828 10.00596,-16.96662 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 427.21079,92.530633 -28.2777,43.939197 18.27174,12.18116 28.2777,-43.93919 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 360.21439,86.875093 -9.13587,15.226457 39.58878,24.79736 9.13587,-14.35637 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 394.86582,9.472205 -29.58282,50.029766 26.10249,16.53158 30.88795,-50.02978 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 232.74722,39.455566 -6.09058,19.576869 21.75208,6.960665 6.09058,-18.706786 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 190.11315,32.929943 -4.35042,23.492243 23.05721,4.785457 4.35041,-23.057201 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 161.83545,23.794071 17.40166,5.220498 -6.09058,23.927285 -17.8367,-6.090582 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 354.54093,577.40427 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 328.08553,568.17564 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>   
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 298.86155,571.25185 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 265.02327,578.32713 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 226.57067,584.47955 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 184.119,576.4814 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 150.89595,581.09572 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 119.04926,586.01766 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 146.60058,4.6042554 h -6.57465 V 16.304109 l -10.95773,40.54135 -2.79014,9.655026 -2.5669,9.706155 -1.5625,9.278 3.04891,3.822735 4.30192,-2.03664 1.52699,-6.59213 1.51677,-7.664099 1.72987,-8.006358 77.25208,19.862541 10.40985,1.632537 101.10559,12.215169 1.88355,-6.245694 -100.2497,-13.043804 -87.66194,-21.49508 10.95775,-39.180902 z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="M 381.17475,4.0592369 C 367.21517,29.839172 351.33443,55.619106 339.4665,81.399041 c -10.65482,8.821069 -12.27478,16.943774 -19.05874,25.411649 -0.0687,3.27136 1.93385,3.87968 4.41942,3.86699 L 347.20047,80.5704 387.25145,6.2689456 c -0.52067,-2.8219703 -1.89786,-4.5061728 -6.0767,-2.2097087 z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>   
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 462.38154,376.39515 8.28641,4.97185 -60.76699,87.83592 -43.64174,61.87184 -21.54466,26.5165 -23.75437,7.73398 -212.68446,10.49612 -1.10486,-7.73398 212.68446,-11.60097 20.43981,-7.73398 33.14563,-45.29903 z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1000,374.5 -18.75,13.28125 -175,73.4375 -8.59375,-2.34375 -82.03125,-50 -5.46875,5.46875 78.90625,50.78125 13.06176,1.59199 8.2864,-0.55242 17.81578,-6.35292 170.99231,-72.42103 7.81255,-7.03125 z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="M 1355.6563,433.29515 680.59028,6.8213731 676.17086,11.24079 1353.4466,443.23884 Z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <path class="part" d="m 1301.5625,412.19531 7.8125,4.6875 -55.4687,38.47656 c 0,0 -38.4766,26.36719 -39.4532,26.36719 -0.9765,0 -8.789,2.92969 -8.789,2.92969 l -11.3166,1.3957 -17.9538,-0.55243 -11.8772,-5.24806 -132.5825,-87.83592 -103.58014,-64.35777 -116.83834,-73.74902 -33.42185,-21.54466 -13.81068,-3.59078 -6.62912,-1.10485 -11.87719,2.76213 -8.56262,5.52427 -15.46796,14.91554 -74.57767,70.15825 -48.33737,39.49854 -38.94612,34.25049 -14.63932,10.77233 -11.60097,3.59077 -9.94369,0.27622 -89.21699,-51.09952 -12.01071,-6.37978 -12.5723,-6.87847 -41.70825,-27.34515 -5.71587,-7.95534 7.09251,-0.82051 57.89956,33.23088 22.41019,14.25781 20.02913,10.83796 30.9609,19.84434 9.71169,5.87307 14.22499,6.35291 10.91044,0.13811 9.52937,-4.83374 55.93325,-47.23253 -29.27864,-36.18397 -24.72111,-31.35025 5.10995,-3.72888 49.16602,60.76699 5.24805,5.80048 39.08423,-32.17888 78.82201,-75.49503 -78.125,-51.95313 -25.78125,-14.84375 3.51562,-5.46875 25.39063,14.84375 25.78125,-37.89062 5.07812,2.73437 -24.60937,37.5 74.21875,49.21875 11.71875,-5.85937 10.9375,-4.29688 19.92187,2.73438 21.09375,10.9375 126.5625,80.07812 156.6406,99.21875 91.7969,59.375 19.9219,5.85938 15.625,-0.78125 z" fill="#789A5F">
  </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задайте размеры для `.map` и меняйте размер обертки SVG-элемента так, как вам необходимо.

```js
$('.part').hover(
  function() {
    $('.description').html($(this).attr('description-data'));
    $('.description').fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $('.description').fadeOut(1);
  }
)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(../img/grid.jpg) repeat;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.part {
  opacity: .3;
}

.part:hover {
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 10px #ccc;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: calc(50% - 200px);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.description img {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Интерактивная карта</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content=" ">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="map">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 662">
    <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/1.jpg'> Мощно."></path>
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 666.12794,242.6834 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.85671,381.31123 17.70329,8.50142 8.37328,-16.95909 -17.95597,-8.75942 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 364.5027,269.75233 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,354.8261 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 457.8629,407.85911 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 438.52794,447.63388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 361.18814,458.68241 8.5976,7.21778 7.0639,-8.08786 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 380.52309,437.13775 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 393.22891,420.01251 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 368.92212,550.38533 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 379.97066,522.76397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 399.30561,492.93291 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 635.92316,259.30512 13.52116,11.21884 11.10914,-12.57123 -13.68345,-11.4954 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 570.29179,252.37179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 540.60429,239.87179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 396.46366,286.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 426.15116,306.66867 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 453.88554,326.59054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 513.65116,357.44993 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 479.66679,339.48117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 552.32303,326.98117 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 587.47928,303.54367 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 619.51054,278.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 737.35191,384.86418 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 762.42044,409.09176 10.00908,3.84657 4.34309,-10.37214 -10.15451,-3.98089 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 835.36871,399.06991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 801.77496,415.47616 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 870.52496,388.91366 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1019.5465,416.09124 8.3179,6.76687 7.3516,-8.50865 -8.4144,-6.93973 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 975.99371,413.13241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 936.93121,422.50741 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 911.93121,442.81991 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.89996,449.85116 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 849.43121,456.88241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 825.99371,469.38241 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 793.92242,478.74251 5.21735,9.36788 9.9817,-5.17779 -5.24289,-9.56418 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 752.32304,474.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 721.07304,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 690.60429,430.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 504.66679,455.49679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 572.63554,393.77804 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 600.76054,371.12179 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 625.76054,349.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 655.44804,324.24679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 685.13554,303.15304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 802.32304,295.34054 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 742.16679,184.40304 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 717.94804,161.74679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 818.59784,217.82417 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 851.74347,237.71155 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 879.91726,255.38921 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 906.98619,276.38145 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 937.92211,291.84941 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 966.64832,308.42223 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 861.13473,315.05136 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 890.9658,333.83388 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 924.6639,354.82611 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1037.359,437.13776 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1066.6377,448.73873 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1093.7065,465.86397 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1122.9852,482.43679 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1224.7151,393.76316 15.2144,9.97674 9.3518,-13.10396 -15.4178,-10.23515 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat1.jpg'> ул.Азамат,1"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1284.9949,443.66556 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad" description-data="<img src='media/azamat5.jpg'> ул.Азамат,5"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1189.6159,408.49403 4.7932,10.1512 9.7978,-4.39428 -4.8127,-10.35602 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 999.00976,327.22136 8.59764,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1025.4651,345.98622 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1052.5358,361.36727 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1162.9716,437.04199 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1083.2978,383.51597 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1118.0589,405.04942 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1185.4279,365.67396 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1153.1277,348.75482 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1119.5971,324.14514 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1086.6817,304.45742 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1059.3236,291.00257 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1038.4417,274.471 8.5975,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1006.2486,250.97876 8.5976,7.21777 7.0639,-8.08785 -8.7008,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 971.01023,232.70701 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 948.82312,217.48056 8.59753,7.21777 7.06395,-8.08785 -8.70082,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 919.24029,198.77377 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 892.26772,183.11227 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 863.11994,158.74995 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 814.83033,130.90729 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.3957 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 784.37742,107.8501 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395715 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 754.7946,93.058683 8.59753,7.217777 7.06396,-8.08786 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 728.69211,77.397188 8.59753,7.217768 7.06396,-8.087851 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 696.93407,54.339988 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.08785 -8.70083,-7.395711 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 674.31438,42.065815 8.59753,7.21777 7.06396,-8.087853 -8.70083,-7.395706 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 484.63627,0.3018283 -14.35637,22.1871177 100.92963,61.775898 5.65554,-8.70083 -4.35041,-2.61025 6.09058,-9.570913 -45.24432,-30.452908 2.17521,-3.915374 -9.13588,-6.960664 1.74017,-4.350415 -26.10249,-17.4016617 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 436.34666,39.020525 -10.00596,17.401661 31.32299,19.141828 10.00596,-16.96662 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 427.21079,92.530633 -28.2777,43.939197 18.27174,12.18116 28.2777,-43.93919 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 360.21439,86.875093 -9.13587,15.226457 39.58878,24.79736 9.13587,-14.35637 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 394.86582,9.472205 -29.58282,50.029766 26.10249,16.53158 30.88795,-50.02978 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 232.74722,39.455566 -6.09058,19.576869 21.75208,6.960665 6.09058,-18.706786 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 190.11315,32.929943 -4.35042,23.492243 23.05721,4.785457 4.35041,-23.057201 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 161.83545,23.794071 17.40166,5.220498 -6.09058,23.927285 -17.8367,-6.090582 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 354.54093,577.40427 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 328.08553,568.17564 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 298.86155,571.25185 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 265.02327,578.32713 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 226.57067,584.47955 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 184.119,576.4814 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 150.89595,581.09572 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 119.04926,586.01766 0.30762,10.15148 9.84386,0.30763 v -10.15149 z" fill="#1669ad"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 146.60058,4.6042554 h -6.57465 V 16.304109 l -10.95773,40.54135 -2.79014,9.655026 -2.5669,9.706155 -1.5625,9.278 3.04891,3.822735 4.30192,-2.03664 1.52699,-6.59213 1.51677,-7.664099 1.72987,-8.006358 77.25208,19.862541 10.40985,1.632537 101.10559,12.215169 1.88355,-6.245694 -100.2497,-13.043804 -87.66194,-21.49508 10.95775,-39.180902 z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 381.17475,4.0592369 C 367.21517,29.839172 351.33443,55.619106 339.4665,81.399041 c -10.65482,8.821069 -12.27478,16.943774 -19.05874,25.411649 -0.0687,3.27136 1.93385,3.87968 4.41942,3.86699 L 347.20047,80.5704 387.25145,6.2689456 c -0.52067,-2.8219703 -1.89786,-4.5061728 -6.0767,-2.2097087 z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>   
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 462.38154,376.39515 8.28641,4.97185 -60.76699,87.83592 -43.64174,61.87184 -21.54466,26.5165 -23.75437,7.73398 -212.68446,10.49612 -1.10486,-7.73398 212.68446,-11.60097 20.43981,-7.73398 33.14563,-45.29903 z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1000,374.5 -18.75,13.28125 -175,73.4375 -8.59375,-2.34375 -82.03125,-50 -5.46875,5.46875 78.90625,50.78125 13.06176,1.59199 8.2864,-0.55242 17.81578,-6.35292 170.99231,-72.42103 7.81255,-7.03125 z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="M 1355.6563,433.29515 680.59028,6.8213731 676.17086,11.24079 1353.4466,443.23884 Z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
    <path class="part" d="m 1301.5625,412.19531 7.8125,4.6875 -55.4687,38.47656 c 0,0 -38.4766,26.36719 -39.4532,26.36719 -0.9765,0 -8.789,2.92969 -8.789,2.92969 l -11.3166,1.3957 -17.9538,-0.55243 -11.8772,-5.24806 -132.5825,-87.83592 -103.58014,-64.35777 -116.83834,-73.74902 -33.42185,-21.54466 -13.81068,-3.59078 -6.62912,-1.10485 -11.87719,2.76213 -8.56262,5.52427 -15.46796,14.91554 -74.57767,70.15825 -48.33737,39.49854 -38.94612,34.25049 -14.63932,10.77233 -11.60097,3.59077 -9.94369,0.27622 -89.21699,-51.09952 -12.01071,-6.37978 -12.5723,-6.87847 -41.70825,-27.34515 -5.71587,-7.95534 7.09251,-0.82051 57.89956,33.23088 22.41019,14.25781 20.02913,10.83796 30.9609,19.84434 9.71169,5.87307 14.22499,6.35291 10.91044,0.13811 9.52937,-4.83374 55.93325,-47.23253 -29.27864,-36.18397 -24.72111,-31.35025 5.10995,-3.72888 49.16602,60.76699 5.24805,5.80048 39.08423,-32.17888 78.82201,-75.49503 -78.125,-51.95313 -25.78125,-14.84375 3.51562,-5.46875 25.39063,14.84375 25.78125,-37.89062 5.07812,2.73437 -24.60937,37.5 74.21875,49.21875 11.71875,-5.85937 10.9375,-4.29688 19.92187,2.73438 21.09375,10.9375 126.5625,80.07812 156.6406,99.21875 91.7969,59.375 19.9219,5.85938 15.625,-0.78125 z" fill="#789A5F"></path>
    </a>
   </svg>

    <div class="description">

    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/6/11/cd5c7ea4f7730c36437201943392a4ac-full.png" alt="">

  </div>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```